# How to hide an OpenBSD 5.3 server as it would be a windows server or something else?

Tags: security

There is an OpenBSD 5.3 server. It only listens on port 443 with an apache (on higher port an sshd listens, but port knocking is used).

How can I hide the servers operating system/webserver to be recognized as something else thatn OpenBSD. ex.: some Linux distribution, etc.

Comment: For the record: security through obscurity is not security at all. Port knocking and obfuscation of the running operating system are not good security measures. You should only do this as an educational exercise.

Comment: I know that, thanks, but it would obviously help from automated scripts that are searching for 0 days for given OS/webserver :) security should be always multilevel'ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a server to "look like something else", you should have an awareness of passive OS fingerprinting.  Michal Zalewski's [p0f v3](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) could be used to unmask your server based on TCP handshake's initial "SYN" packet, or on TCP connection take down.

When acting as a NAT router, OpenBSD can "scrub" routed packets to make OS identification harder, but it's not clear to me if OpenBSD can mark up its own TCP packets to avoid such passive identification.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to re-use work done for Anonym.OS: http://kaos.to/blog/archives/2006/02/23/anonymos-livecd/

Answer (score 0):

Whom you aware?

nmap?

Than you should take latest nmap source, compare what's the difference between windows and openbsd (opt -O of nmap), look for this settings via sysctl on bsd, than change defaults in /etc/sysctl.conf.

Probably somewhere you'll need to rebuild kernel.

I do not did it myself.

But as my opinion, you should have 7-8 kernels for linux/netbsd/windows nt-95-xp-vista, etc.

Than change on boot /boot/currentkernel to /boot/random_one, and be happy that at next boot your system will looks like completely another OS.